What is the input to Contrastive Learning models
Contrastive Learning has been used in deep learning for many tasks. The architecture of simCLR is given below. I am using the implementation in the link link. It takes two images as an input not one image as an input. If I want to use it as a feature extractor, what will be the input? Let I be an image whose feature needs to be extracted then input will two copies of I or something else.

